# How i convert react class based componet into functional component code in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I am learning ReactJs and I am trying to implement below react classs based component into functional component but I am having difficulties in it. When I implement this into functional component it does not updates the webpage.

I want to convert this code into functional component.

so anyone can convert this code into react-functional component please..

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';  
  
class Home extends Component { 

  constructor(props){  
    super(props);
    
 
    this.state = {  
        tabType:'none'
    }  
  }  

  toggleMe=(value) =>{
    this.setState({
      tabType:value
    })
  }
  
  render() {  

    return ( 

      <div className='home_css'>

        <div>

          {
            this.state.tabType==='none' && 
            <div>
              <button className='button_css' onClick={() => this.toggleMe('general')}>General</button>
              <button className='button_css' onClick={() => this.toggleMe('army')}>Army</button>
              <button className='button_css' onClick={() => this.toggleMe('police')}>Police</button>
              <button className='button_css' onClick={() => this.toggleMe('psi')}>PSI</button>
            </div>
          }

          {
            this.state.tabType==='general' && 
            <div className='card'>
              I am General division  
              <button onClick={() => this.toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
            </div>
          }
          {
            this.state.tabType==='army' && <div className='card'>
              I am Army division
              <button onClick={() => this.toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
            </div>
          }
          {
            this.state.tabType==='police' && <div className='card'>
              I am Police division
              <button onClick={() => this.toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
            </div>
          }
          {
            this.state.tabType==='psi' && <div className='card'>
              I am PSI division
              <button onClick={() => this.toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
              </div>
          }

        </div>
     
      </div>
    );  
  }  
}  
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well In functional code format, we use hooks instead of this.state and all. So the code will look something like this.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';


export default function Home(){

    const [tabType,setTabType] = useState('none');

    const toggleMe=(value)=>{
        setTabType(value);
    }


return ( 

    <div className='home_css'>

      <div>

        {
          tabType==='none' && 
          <div>
            <button className='button_css' onClick={() => toggleMe('general')}>General</button>
            <button className='button_css' onClick={() => toggleMe('army')}>Army</button>
            <button className='button_css' onClick={() => toggleMe('police')}>Police</button>
            <button className='button_css' onClick={() => toggleMe('psi')}>PSI</button>
          </div>
        }

        {
          tabType==='general' && 
          <div className='card'>
            I am General division  
            <button onClick={() => toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
          </div>
        }
        {
          tabType==='army' && <div className='card'>
            I am Army division
            <button onClick={() => toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
          </div>
        }
        {
          tabType==='police' && <div className='card'>
            I am Police division
            <button onClick={() => toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
          </div>
        }
        {
          tabType==='psi' && <div className='card'>
            I am PSI division
            <button onClick={() => toggleMe('none')}>Close</button>
            </div>
        }

      </div>
   
    </div>
  );  
 }
```